# how to use a scaled object(MC) to fill the background with the new properties

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a stage 300 to 200 and all object that i have are for this dimensions.Also have an pattern function that fills the background.
But the user is thinking of resizing the stage to lets say 1024 to 480 (he switched from a phone to a tablet).And now the scale of the objects in the tablet screen are more than 3times before(when seen on the Phone)
How do i save the current new size object and use it in the creation of the new background (the 1024x480).
i have this code

```
public static const GAME_ORG_WIDTH:uint = 300;
public static const GAME_ORG_HEIGHT:uint = 200;
private var myC:MyClip = new MyClip();

public function MainClass_road() {
                          addEventListener(Event.ADDED, init);
                }

                public function init(e:Event):void{
                           stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                             stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                             stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, setUpScreen);
                }

                public function setUpScreen(ev:Event):void{

                          stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, setUpScreen);
                          if(stage.fullScreenHeight > stage.fullScreenWidth){   
                                    gameStageWidth = stage.fullScreenWidth;
                        gameStageHeight = stage.fullScreenHeight;
                          }else {
                                    gameStageWidth = stage.fullScreenHeight;       // 480
                                    gameStageHeight = stage.fullScreenWidth;                     //1024
                          }
                          rescaleRatio = gameStageWidth / GAME_ORG_WIDTH;   
                          //rescale every object, ie:
                        myC.scaleX = myC.scaleY =   rescaleRatio;
               //start filling the Background with the pattern
                               tileBgF();
                }
```

so before the tileBgF() how do i save the new dimensions of the object and use them(the new values)to fill the screen with this function .cause right now im just using the old object properties (sizes), not the updated one.

```
public function tileBgF(e:Event=null):void {
                var bgClip:MovieClip = new myC();
                var i:int = 0;
                var j:int = 0;
                while (bgClip.x < gameStageWidth - bgClip.width) {
                    bgClip = MyC;
                    while (bgClip.y < gameStageHeight - bgClip.height) {
                        bgClip = MyC;
                        tileLayer.addChild(bgClip);
                        bgClip.x = bgClip.width * i;
                        bgClip.y = bgClip.height * j;

                        j++;
                    }

                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }

                addChildAt(tileLayer,0);
            }
```

and if i decide in the future to use the background again (so i have 2 backgrounds at the same time on the stage) is it enough just to make another tileLayer and add it again or i need to do something more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bgClip = new MyClip();
bgClip.scaleX = bgClip.scaleY = scaleRatio
tileLayer.addChild(bgClip);
bgClip.x = bgClip.width * i;
bgClip.y = bgClip.height * j;
```